# Validacion de formulario con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validación

**Una pregunta como podria que esta funcion de js me deje ingresar espacios en mi input**

**este es el codigo (ES DE UN TUTO DE YOUTUBE)**

```
function SoloLetras(e)
    {
    key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    tecla = String.fromCharCode(key).toString();
    letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÁÉÍÓÚabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzáéíóú ";
    
    especiales = [8,13];
    tecla_especial = false
    for(var i in especiales) {
    if(key == especiales[i]){
     tecla_especial = true;
     break;
    }
    }
    
    if(letras.indexOf(tecla) == -1 && !tecla_especial)
    {
     alert("Ingresar solo letras");
     return false;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te conviene emplear una [expresión regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
let texto1 = "Hola Mundo",
    texto2 = "123",
    regex = /^[a-z\s]+$/gi;
    
console.log(regex.test(texto1)); //true
console.log(regex.test(texto2)); //false
```

Esa expresión regular solo valida cadenas de caracteres que contengan letras y espacios, pudiendo ser más de uno (el signo `+`) y no hace distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas (el indicador `i`).